# Calendar displaying data fetched from API using VUE.JS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, calendar

I used the https://element-plus.org/en-US/component/calendar.html#basic    link to create a calendar using vue.js.
Now I need to display data in the calendar which has been fetched from API. When I click on a particular date in the calendar the data on a particular date has to be displayed on the right side of the calendar in a box.
Attached the UI below
[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NPWJj.png]

for calender I have used below code

```
<template>
<el-calendar v-model="value" />
</template>

<script lang="ts" setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'
const value = ref(new Date())
</script>
```

And for fetching API data used the below code in metrics.ts

```
import request from '@/network'
import type { ResponseData } from '@/network/type'
import axios from 'axios';


export function getMetricsdata(projectId: number) {
    return request.get<ResponseData>({
        url: 'Sample/api/url/needed',


    })
}


export function getRepo() {
    return request.get<ResponseData>({
        url: '/Sample/api/url/needed',


    })
}

export function getTeam() {
    return request.get<ResponseData>({
        url: '/Sample/api/url/needed',


    })
}
export function getBuildNumber() {
    return request.post<ResponseData>({
        url: '/Sample/api/url/needed',
        params: {
            branchId: "1776",
            startTime: "2023-07-10 00:00:00 00:00:00",
            endTime: "2023-07-17 23:59:59 23:59:59",
            buildNumbers: ' '
        }
    })
}

export function getRecipe() {
    return request.post<ResponseData>({
        url: '/Sample/api/url/needed',
        params: {
            branchId: "1776",
            module: " ",
            startTime: "2023-07-10 00:00:00 00:00:00",
            endTime: "2023-07-17 23:59:59 23:59:59",
            buildNumbers: ' '
        }
    })
}

export function getCalData1() {
    return request.get<ResponseData>({
        url: 'Sample/api/url/needed',


    })
}

export function getCalData(date, repo, impactProducts) {
    console.log('date', date);
    console.log('repo', repo);
    console.log('impact', impactProducts)
    return request.get<ResponseData>({
        url: `/api/feature-commit-detail/get?startTime=${date}-01+00%3A00%3A00&endTime=${date}-31+23%3A59%3A59&repo=${repo}&impactProducts=${impactProducts}`
    });
}
```

To return required data from API data used below code in event-utils.ts

```
import type { EventInput } from '@fullcalendar/core';
import { getCalData,getCalData1 } from './api/metrics';
let month, repo, impactProducts,apiResponse;
export function setEventData(data) {
  console.log('data',data)
  month = data.month;
  repo = data.repo;
  impactProducts = data.impactProducts;

}

let eventGuid = 0;
let todayStr = new Date().toISOString().replace(/T.*$/, ''); // YYYY-MM-DD of today
// getEventData();

if(month==null &&  repo==null && impactProducts==null)
{
   apiResponse=await getCalData1();
   
}
else
{
   apiResponse=await getCalData(month,repo,impactProducts);
}


console.log(apiResponse.result);

export const INITIAL_EVENTS: EventInput[] =apiResponse.result.map((item) => {
  const repoName = item.repo;
  const strattime = item.updateTime;
  const committerName = item.committer;
  const commitMessage = item.commitMessage;
  const commitTime = item.commitTime;
  const mergeTime = item.mergeTime;
  
  return {
    id: createEventId(),
    title: ` ${repoName}`,
    start: `${strattime}`,
    committer: `${committerName}`,
    message: `${commitMessage}`,
    time: `${commitTime}`,
    merge: `${mergeTime}`
  };
});
export function createEventId() {
  return String(eventGuid++);
}

let eventData = null;
```

For calender view used below code in SCMCalendar.vue

```
<template>
    <el-row :gutter="20">
        <el-col :span="4">
            <el-menu default-active="1" class="el-menu-vertical-demo" :collapse="isCollapse">
                <div class="title-box">
                    <el-image :class="{ largeImg: !isCollapse, smallImg: isCollapse }"
                        src="https://fuss10.elemecdn.com/e/5d/4a731a90594a4af544c0c25941171jpeg.jpeg"></el-image>
                    <div style="margin-left: 10px; margin-top: 10px">
                        <span v-show="!isCollapse">{{ areaName }}</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="nav-collapse">
                    <el-icon style="width: 3em" v-show="!isCollapse" @click="fold">
                        <Fold />
                    </el-icon>
                    <el-icon style="width: 3em" v-show="isCollapse" @click="unFold">
                        <Expand />
                    </el-icon>
                </div>
                <router-link to="/metrics/SCMCalendar">
                    <el-menu-item index="1">

                        <el-icon>
                            <Calendar />
                        </el-icon>

                        <template #title>
                            Calendar</template>

                    </el-menu-item>
                </router-link>
                <el-sub-menu index="2">
                    <template #title>
                        <el-icon>
                            <Monitor />
                        </el-icon>
                        <span>Monitor & Trace</span>
                    </template>
                    <el-menu-item index="2-1">Issue History</el-menu-item>
                </el-sub-menu>
                <el-sub-menu index="3">
                    <template #title>
                        <el-icon>
                            <Histogram />
                        </el-icon>
                        <span>Metrics</span>
                    </template>
                    <router-link to="/metrics/ChangeLeadTime">
                        <el-menu-item index="3-1">ChangeLeadTime</el-menu-item>
                    </router-link>
                    <router-link to="/metrics/pipelineCriticalPath">
                        <el-menu-item index="3-2">PipelineCritical Path</el-menu-item>
                    </router-link>
                    <router-link to="/metrics/componentBuildTime">
                        <el-menu-item index="3-3">Component Build Time</el-menu-item>
                    </router-link>
                    <router-link to="/metrics/componentCompileTime">
                        <el-menu-item index="3-4">Component Compile Time</el-menu-item>
                    </router-link>
                    <router-link to="/metrics/buildSuccessRate">
                        <el-menu-item index="3-5">Component Success Rate</el-menu-item>
                    </router-link>
                    <router-link to="/metrics/qualityIssueAnalyze">
                        <el-menu-item index="3-6">Quality Issue Analyze</el-menu-item>
                    </router-link>
                </el-sub-menu>
                <el-sub-menu index="4">
                    <template #title>
                        <el-icon>
                            <Management />
                        </el-icon>
                        <span>Management</span>
                    </template>
                    <el-menu-item index="4-1">Source</el-menu-item>
                    <el-menu-item index="4-2">Permission</el-menu-item>
                    <el-menu-item index="4-3">Metrics & Report</el-menu-item>
                    <el-menu-item index="4-4">Notification</el-menu-item>
                </el-sub-menu>
            </el-menu>
        </el-col>
        <el-col :span="20">
            <el-main :style="{
                marginLeft: elMainWidth
            }">

                <div style="margin: 20px;">
                    <el-form :inline="true" :model="formInline" class="demo-form-inline">
                        <el-form-item style="width: 300px;" label="Date">
                            <el-date-picker v-model="value2" type="daterange" unlink-panels range-separator="To"
                                start-placeholder="Start date" end-placeholder="End date" :shortcuts="shortcuts" />
                        </el-form-item>

                        
                        <el-form-item style="width: 270px;" label="Team">
                            <el-select v-model="formInline1.Team" placeholder="Team" multiple collapse-tags filterable
                                @change="handleTeamChange">
                                <el-option v-if="!allSelected" :key="selectAllValue" label="Select All"
                                    :value="selectAllValue" @click="selectAllTeams" />
                                <el-option v-for="option in filteredTeamOptions" :key="option.value" :label="option.label"
                                    :value="option.label" />
                            </el-select>
                        </el-form-item>
                        <el-form-item style="width: 270px;" label="Cycle">
                            <el-select v-model="formInline.Cycle" placeholder="Cycle">
                                <el-option label="Day" value="Day" />
                                <el-option label="Week" value="week" />
                                <el-option label="Month" value="Month" />

                            </el-select>
                        </el-form-item>

                    </el-form>
                    <div id="chart"></div>
                </div>

                <div style="margin: 20px;">
                    <el-form :inline="true" :model="formInline" class="demo-form-inline">
                        <el-form-item style="width: 220px;" label="Month">
                            <el-date-picker v-model="selectedMonth" type="month" placeholder="Pick a month" />
                        </el-form-item>
                        <el-form-item style="width: 220px;" label="Repo">
                            <el-select v-model="selectedRepo" placeholder="Repo">
                                <el-option v-for="option in RepoOptions" :key="option" :label="option"
                                    :value="option"></el-option>
                            </el-select>
                        </el-form-item>
                        <el-form-item style="width: 300px;" label="Impact Products">
                            <el-select v-model="selectedImpactProducts" placeholder="Impact Products">
                                <el-option label="All" value="All" />
                                <el-option label="SRAN" value="SRAN" />
                                <el-option label="CRAN" value="CRAN" />
                                <el-option label="SRAN, CRAN" value="SRAN, CRAN" />
                            </el-select>
                        </el-form-item>
                        <el-form-item>
                            <el-button type="primary" @click="onSubmit">Update</el-button>
                        </el-form-item>
                    </el-form>
                </div>
                <el-space wrap>
                    <div class="cards-container">
                        <el-card class="box-card" style="padding: 0%; margin: 0%;">
                            <div>
                                <calander></calander>

                            </div>


                        </el-card>
                        <el-card class="box-card" style="width: auto;">

                            <div class="card-header">
                                <span>Event Details</span>
                                <el-scrollbar height="580px">
                                    <div class="card-header">

                                        <el-button class="button4" text>Gerrit</el-button>
                                        <el-button class="button5" text>Team</el-button>
                                        <el-button class="button6" text>Impact</el-button>
                                        <el-icon @click="dialogVisible = true">
                                            <Setting />
                                        </el-icon>
                                        <el-dialog v-model="dialogVisible" title="Edit event:" width="30%" draggable>
                                            <el-form :inline="true" :model="formInline" class="demo-form-inline">
                                                <el-form-item label="Node Selected">
                                                    <el-select v-model="formInline.node" placeholder="Nodes">
                                                        <el-option label="Node one" value="Node one" />
                                                        <el-option label="Node two" value="Node two" />
                                                    </el-select>
                                                </el-form-item>
                                                <el-form-item label="Impacted Products">
                                                    <el-select v-model="formInline.impact" placeholder="Products">
                                                        <el-option label="ABC" value="ABC" />
                                                        <el-option label="DEF" value="DEF" />
                                                        <el-option label="ABC, DEF" value="ABC, DEF" />
                                                    </el-select>
                                                </el-form-item>
                                            </el-form>
                                            <template #footer>
                                                <span class="dialog-footer">
                                                    <el-button @click="dialogVisible = false">Cancel</el-button>
                                                    <el-button type="primary" @click="dialogVisible = false">
                                                        Save
                                                    </el-button>
                                                </span>
                                            </template>
                                        </el-dialog>
                                    </div>

                                    <p v-for="item in 10" :key="item" class="scrollbar-demo-item">Committer:
                                        <br>Commit message:
                                        <br>Commit time:
                                        <br>Merge time:
                                    </p>


                                </el-scrollbar>

                            </div>


                        </el-card>
                    </div>
                </el-space>

            </el-main>


        </el-col>



    </el-row>
</template> 
<script lang="ts">
export default {
    components: {
        calander,
    },
    data() {
        return {
            formInline1: {
                Team: [],
                Cycle: [],
                Repo: [],
            },
            selectedMonth: '',
            selectedRepo: '',
            selectedImpactProducts: '',

            TeamOptions: [


            ],
            CycleOptions: [

                { value: 'Buildnumber1', label: 'Buildnumber 1' },
                { value: 'Buildnumber2', label: 'Buildnumber 2' },
                { value: 'Buildnumber3', label: 'Buildnumber 3' },
                // ...
            ],
            RepoOptions: [


                // ...
            ],
            searchQuery: '',
            selectAllValue: 'selectAll',
        };
    },
    computed: {
        filteredTeamOptions() {
            const searchQuery = this.searchQuery.toLowerCase();
            return this.TeamOptions.filter(
                (option) =>
                    option.label.toLowerCase().includes(searchQuery) || option.value.toLowerCase().includes(searchQuery)
            );
        },
        filteredCycleptions() {
            const searchQuery = this.searchQuery.toLowerCase();
            return this.CycleOptions.filter(
                (option) =>
                    option.label.toLowerCase().includes(searchQuery) || option.value.toLowerCase().includes(searchQuery)
            );
        },
        filteredRepoptions() {
            const searchQuery = this.searchQuery.toLowerCase();
            return this.RepoOptions.filter(
                (option) =>
                    option.label.toLowerCase().includes(searchQuery) || option.value.toLowerCase().includes(searchQuery)
            );
        },
        allSelected() {
            return this.formInline1.Team.length === this.filteredTeamOptions.length;
        },

        allSelected1() {
            return this.formInline1.Cycle.length === this.filteredCycleptions.length;
        },
        allSelected2() {
            return this.formInline1.Repo.length === this.filteredRepoptions.length;
        },
    },


    methods: {
        onSubmit() {
            // Pass the selected values to the eventutil.ts file
            const eventData = {
                month: this.selectedMonth,
                repo: this.selectedRepo,
                impactProducts: this.selectedImpactProducts
            };

            setEventData(eventData);

            // Continue with your other code or navigation logic
            // ...
        },
        // onSubmit() {
        //   // Pass the selected values to the other TypeScript page
        //   // Replace the router.push() call with your specific implementation
        
        handleTeamChange(value) {
            if (value.includes('selectAll')) {
                if (value.length === this.TeamOptions.length - 1) {
                    // If "selectAll" is selected along with all other options, select all options
                    this.formInline1.Team = this.TeamOptions.map((option) => option.value);
                } else {
                    // If "selectAll" is selected but not all other options are selected, remove other options and select "selectAll"
                    this.formInline1.Team = ['selectAll'];
                }
            } else if (this.formInline1.Team.includes('selectAll')) {
                // If "selectAll" was previously selected but now other options are selected, remove "selectAll"
                this.formInline1.Team = value.filter((item) => item !== 'selectAll');
            } else {
                // If "selectAll" was not selected and other options are selected, update the selected options
                this.formInline1.Team = value;
            }
        },
        handleCycleChange(selectedCycle) {
            if (selectedCycle.includes(this.selectAllValue)) {
                this.formInline1.Cycle = selectedCycle.length === this.filteredCycleptions.length ? [] : this.filteredCycleptions.map((option) => option.value);
            }
        },

        handleRepoChange(selectedRepo) {
            if (selectedRepo.includes(this.selectAllValue)) {
                this.formInline1.Repo = selectedRepo.length === this.filteredRepoptions.length ? [] : this.filteredRepoptions.map((option) => option.value);
            }
        },
        GetRepo() {
            console.log('testmetrics2');
            getRepo()
                .then((res) => {
                    console.log('res.result2:', res.result);
                    this.RepoOptions = res.result;
                    updateChart(); // Update the chart based on initial selections
                })
                .catch((err) => {
                    console.log(err);
                });
        },
        GetTeam() {
            console.log('team1')
            getTeam()
                .then((res) => {
                    console.log('team:', res.result);
                    this.TeamOptions = res.result.map((item) => ({
                        value: item.id,
                        label: item.teamName
                    }));
                    // updateChart(); // Update the chart based on initial selections
                })
                .catch((err) => {
                    console.log(err);
                });
        },
       
    },
    mounted() {
        this.GetRepo();
        this.GetTeam();
        // Call the function to retrieve the repo options
    },



};
</script>
<script lang = "ts" setup >

import ApexCharts from 'apexcharts';
import { ElMessage, ElMessageBox } from 'element-plus'
import type { Action } from 'element-plus'
import { Calendar, Expand, Fold, Management, Monitor, Histogram, Setting } from '@element-plus/icons-vue'
import { useRoute } from 'vue-router'
import router from '@/router'
import { getMetricsdata, getRepo, getTeam, getCalData } from '@/api/metrics';
import { ref, onBeforeMount, onMounted, reactive, h, VueElement } from 'vue'
import calander from '@/views/metrics/ComponentCompileTime.vue'
import { setEventData } from '../../event-utils';

const dialogVisible = ref(false)
const route = useRoute()
const isCollapse = ref(false)
const areaName = ref('')
const shortName = ref('')
const elMainWidth = ref('-20px')
const value2 = ref('')
onBeforeMount(() => {
    areaName.value = route.params.areaName as string
})


const fold = () => {
    isCollapse.value = true
    elMainWidth.value = '-256px'
}

const unFold = () => {
    isCollapse.value = false
    elMainWidth.value = '-20px'
}


const open = () => {
    ElMessageBox({
        title: 'Edit Event:',
        message: h('p', null, [
            h('span', null, 'Message can be '),
            h('i', { style: 'color: teal' }, 'VNode'),
        ]),
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonText: 'Save',
        cancelButtonText: 'Cancel',
    })
}



const selectedFromDate = ref('');
const selectedToDate = ref('');

const selectedCycle = ref('day');
const value = ref(new Date());
const value1 = ref('')
const disabledDate = (time: Date) => {
    return time.getTime() > Date.now()
}
const formInline = reactive({
    user: '',

    products: '',
    Cycle: '',
    node: '',
    impact: ''

})



onMounted(() => {
    // GetMetrics();
    // GetRepo();
    const chartOptions = {
        chart: {
            type: 'line',
            height: 250,

        },
        series: [
            {
                name: 'failureNumber',
                data: [30, 40, 35, 50, 49, 60, 70, 91, 125],
            },
            {
                name: 'commitNumber',
                data: [10, 20, 30, 40, 10, 5, 13, 16, 170],

            },
            {
                name: 'prontoNumber',
                data: [5, 67, 90, 176, 30, 3, 90, 1, 125],
            },
        ],
        xaxis: {
            categories: ['build1', 'build2', 'build3', 'build4', 'build5', 'build6', 'build7', 'build8', 'build9'],
        },
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
        },
    };

    const chart = new ApexCharts(document.getElementById('chart'), chartOptions);
    chart.render();
});

function updateChart() {
    // Retrieve selected options
    const fromDate = selectedFromDate.value;
    const toDate = selectedToDate.value;
    const team = selectedTeam.value;
    const cycle = selectedCycle.value;

    // Perform chart data updates based on selected options
    // ...

    // Render chartW
    const chartOptions = {
        // ...
        // Chart options based on selected options
        // ...
    };

    const chart = new ApexCharts(document.getElementById('chart'), chartOptions);
    chart.render();
}


</script>
  
<style scoped lang="scss">
.el-main {
    border: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    height: 835px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 12px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.el-menu-vertical-demo {
    border: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    height: 835px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 12px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.title-box {
    display: flex;
    height: 100px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    font-size: 18px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    box-shadow: 0 2px 12px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.nav-collapse {
    display: flex;
    font-size: 18px;
    height: 45px;
    align-items: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    cursor: pointer;
}

:deep(.el-menu) {
    --el-menu-base-level-padding: 15px;
}

.largeImg {
    width: 48px;
    height: 48px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    border-radius: 40px;
}

.smallImg {
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    border-radius: 40px;
}

.chart {
    width: 100%;
    height: 40%;
    color: blue;
}

.demo-date-picker {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.demo-date-picker .block {
    padding: 30px 0;
    text-align: center;
    border-right: solid 1px var(--el-border-color);
    flex: 1;
}

.demo-date-picker .block:last-child {
    border-right: none;
}

.demo-date-picker .demonstration {
    display: block;
    color: var(--el-text-color-secondary);
    font-size: 14px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.scrollbar-demo-item {
    display: flex;
    /* align-items: center;
justify-content: center; */
    height: 70px;
    margin: 10px;
    width: 250px;
    font-size: small;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background: var(--el-color-primary-light-9);
    color: var(#000000);
}

.button1 {
    background-color: burlywood;
}

.button2 {
    background-color: lightblue;
}

.button3 {
    background-color: palegoldenrod;
}

.button4 {
    background-color: lavender;
}

.button5 {
    background-color: lavender;
}

.button6 {
    background-color: palegoldenrod;
}

.cards-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 2fr 1fr;
    grid-column-gap: 20px;
}
</style>
```

I need the data coming from API to be listed in the calendar according to the date in a list and also when we click on the particular date the data must be displayed in right side event details.

I am new to programming and learning vue.js. If I get steps on how to write this code will be helpful. The code written is correctly or not. please suggest.